# Recovery Mode can't see new drive but USB installer can

Tags: startup, ssd

I'm having a lot of difficulty replacing a dead SSD in a 2013 macbook pro. Before the drive died the computer was running a fairly old version of OS X, seemingly Yosemite.

I bought an OEM replacement SSD from OWC (https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/SSDA13S128S/) which I've successfully installed in the Macbook.

When I boot the computer from a El Capitan install USB I made, I can see and format the new drive, and go through the installation but when it reboots, the computer doesn't find the drive and I get the missing file icon.

If I boot into Internet Recovery, I can't see the drive in Disk Utility.

I'm guessing whatever issue prevents Internet Recovery from seeing the drive is the reason I can't boot, but I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: I'd start with the basics PRAM and SMC resets...Here’s how to reset your PRAM:

Shut down your machine. Yes, all the way down, not sleep or logging out.
Press the power button and then press command-option-p-r. You have to make sure you get those keys pressed before the gray screen comes up or it won’t work.
Hold those keys down until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

Comment: To reset the SMC For MacBook Pros, MacBook Airs, and MacBooks where you can’t remove the battery on your own, here’s what you do:

Turn off your machine (really, you knew this was coming at step one)
Keep the power adapter plugged in.
Press at the same time shift-option-control (on the left side of the machine) and the power button
Let go
Turn your machine back on with the power button.

Comment: Check it's formatted GUID/HFS+ If you just wrote a new partition to it, it may still be MBR underneath.

Comment: I've reset the PRAM and SMC several times already and the drive is freshly formatted it's GUID / HFS+ confirmed through diskutil.

Comment: What I really can't figure out is why I can't see it in Recovery Mode but I _can_ see it if I boot from an external drive / USB